# Micropython code displaying red-white noise on 1.54" ePaper display

Tags: display, esp32, spi, micropython

I have the following code in micropython that is running on my Espressif ESP32-PICO-KIT. To this I have attached a WaveShare 1.54" ePaper display (supporting red color).

When I reach the last line the display updates in waves, but I only get white-red noise on the display.

I'm using the driver from [mcauser/micropython-waveshare-epaper](https://github.com/mcauser/micropython-waveshare-epaper) on Github.

This is my code:

```
from machine import Pin, SoftSPI
import epaper1in54b

miso = Pin(19)
sck = Pin(18) # yellow 
mosi = Pin(23) # white 

cs = Pin(5) # green
dc = Pin(25) # gray
rst = Pin(21) # orange
busy = Pin(19) # gray

spi = SoftSPI(baudrate=20000000, polarity=0, phase=0, sck=sck, mosi=mosi, miso=miso)
e = epaper1in54b.EPD(spi, cs, dc, rst, busy)

e.init()

w = 200
h = 200
x = 0
y = 0


import framebuf
buf = bytearray(w * h // 8)
fb = framebuf.FrameBuffer(buf, w, h, framebuf.MONO_VLSB)
black = 0
white = 1
red = 2
fb.fill(white)
fb.text('Hello world!', 0, 0,black)
e.display_frame(buf,None)
```

The result

[image: Result]

**Update**:

I'm using `MicroPython v1.16 on 2021-06-18; ESP32 module with ESP32`.

> <sub>Please note that I did file a new issue in the [mcauser/micropython-waveshare-epaper](https://github.com/mcauser/micropython-waveshare-epaper/issues/17) repository.</sub>

Comment: Have you established that this device works in other circumstances or is this your first test? Is it the same fixed noise pattern or does it change depending on your `fb.text` argument or on refresh? [also, I assume there's no connectivity issues in your setup]

Comment: Looks like either:
* incorrect baudrate
* incorrect width/height used
* incorrect color value used (if your e-ink has only 2 states - no color & red color, maybe 2 is not a proper value)

Comment: @Salmonstrikes: yes I have used it using an Arduino sketch quite a while ago!

Comment: @Salmonstrikes: Also I do have the same problem when I don't use red at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get an answer on an issue, which I opened over at [Github](https://github.com/mcauser/micropython-waveshare-epaper/issues/17)

> I faced with same problem. This library does not fit new displays.
>
> This library version - 1.54" Black/White/Red GDEW0154Z04 e-paper display driver
>
> Current Eink fw version GDEH0154Z90.
>
> Protocol is changed/ Check the pdf https://v4.cecdn.yun300.cn/100001_1909185148/GDEH0154Z90-0111.pdf
>
> It was easier for me to write new driver. Found few cpp libraries. https://github.com/ZinggJM/GxEPD2/blob/3ecef6f63b8fce27bf8c6dbb399a5dfb768a568f/src/epd3c/GxEPD2_154_Z90c.cpp https://github.com/martinberlin/cale-idf/blob/master/components/CalEPD/models/color/gdeh0154z90.cpp

So it seems that I have the wrong hardware for this library.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know anything about your Espressif ESP32-PICO-KIT, but the v4 datasheet says: `"USB-UART bridge Single-chip USB-UART bridge: CP2102 in V4 provides up to 1 Mbps transfer rates and CP2102N in V4.1 offers up to 3 Mbps transfers rates."`

The 20,000,000 value you have in SoftSPI looks VERY suspicious. Did you mean 2,000,000?

Edit: I just realied this isn't using USB-UART, rather SDIO/SPI.  So, those rate limits above aren't relevant.

Comment: interestingly, the examples show _both_ rates https://github.com/mcauser/micropython-waveshare-epaper/search?q=baudrate

Comment: I tried using `2000000` for the baud rate with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after many, many tests i figure it out (at least I hope so ;))
so this display have 2 buffers, one for B/W and 2nd for the other color (in my case red), so you need to provide additional FB for the red (it's in the driver file:

```
display_frame( frame_buffer_black, frame_buffer_red)
```

So you code should look like this:

```
import framebuf
buf = bytearray(w * h // 8)
fb = framebuf.FrameBuffer(buf, w, h, framebuf.MONO_HLSB)
buf_y = bytearray(w * h // 8)
fb_y = framebuf.FrameBuffer(buf_y, w, h, framebuf.MONO_HLSB)
fb_y.fill(1)
black = 0
white = 1
red = 2
fb.fill(white)
fb.text('Hello world!', 0, 0,black)
e.display_frame(buf,buf_y)
```

There's problem with fb.text (you need to change orientation VLSB -> HLSB) like in my code.
Here is my example:

```
import framebuf
buf = bytearray(w * h // 8)
fb = framebuf.FrameBuffer(buf, w, h, framebuf.MONO_HLSB)
fb.fill(1)
buf_y = bytearray(w * h // 8)
fb_y = framebuf.FrameBuffer(buf_y, w, h, framebuf.MONO_HLSB)
fb_y.fill(1)
e.draw_filled_rectangle(buf, 10, 10, 100, 100, 1)
e.draw_filled_rectangle(buf_y, 100, 100, 190, 190, 1)
e.display_frame(buf,buf_y)
```